# packet marking(IP Traceback) in C#

Tags: c#, packet, ip-protocol, traceback

I'm looking for implementation of IP Traceback using packet marking  algorithm in C#?

I google it but could not find anything!!!

any one know a website has this implementation ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing in C# because C# is not for hardware programing!!!!